# Sending mail from contact form 7 not working

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I created a wordpress template and used contact form 7 for sending mail .
My contact form plugin source code is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        [text* nomcontact placeholder "Nom"]
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        [text* prenomcontact placeholder "Prènom"]
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        [email* emailcontact placeholder "Adresse Email"]
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        [tel* telcontact placeholder "Numero de Téléphone"]
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        [text* entreprise placeholder "Nom d'entreprise"]
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        [text* devissujet placeholder "Sujet de devis ?"]
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        [textarea* textarea-contact placeholder "Votre Message"]
        <div class="text-center">
         <center> [submit class:thm-btn class:contact-one__btn "Demander Devis"]</center>
         </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

and my html source code is :

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0000ms">
                        <div class="pricing-one__single text-center" style="background-image: url(https://www.hostsandguests.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/backhome4.jpg);">

                                         <center>  <form action="#" class="contact-one__form row">
  [contact-form-7 id="7694" title="devis"]

              </form>  <!-- /.contact-one__form --> </center>
                        </div><!-- /.pricing-one__single -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->


                </div><!-- /.row -->
```

email setting  :

[image]

when i click send => "demander devis"  is just refreshing the web page without any message and the mail is not sent .

any help please ?

Comment: add the contact form  shortcode out side of the <form> tag.

Comment: @Hemu999 thank you, but where i cant put the form class : class="contact-one__form row" ??

Comment: @Hemu999 i just change form to div and thats work perfectly thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code for how to add the contact form

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0000ms">
                        <div class="pricing-one__single text-center" style="background-image: url(https://www.hostsandguests.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/backhome4.jpg);">

                                         <center>  <div class="contact-one__form row">
                              [contact-form-7 id="7694" title="devis"]

              </div>  <!-- /.contact-one__form --> </center>
                        </div><!-- /.pricing-one__single -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->


                </div><!-- /.row -->
```